# Laravel first page load is slow

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5

I have a problem with first page load of my website, every page take around 2 to 5 seconds to load for the first time, after the first load if i refresh the page it takes less than 1 second.

Even if the page didn't make any database quires, first page load is slow, i debug the code and found that the problem is with cache. So if i remove the part that read from cache the first load become fast.

The Laravel version is 5.2 and i host the code on Godaddy. Is there any reason that may cause the reading of cache slow for first load?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think Godaddy is a really slow host. The laravel app stores everything in the cache file, for example, the compiled views. Therefore, if the app is not in the cache, it may be slow. You may consider moving to a different host, such as Laravel Forge. May I also ask if the app was slow when in development?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Laravel 7 with Godaddy Linux shared Delux hosting plan. I discovered if the site is not visited for a period of time, the initial page load is slow, like if the server was going on sleep mode.

Godaddy support did not help at all. I could prove my point by recording the load time difference (when not visited for a while and when just reloaded). The loading of a blank page was just as slow. The issue was repeatable.

My solution:

1. Create a simple view reached by requesting http://www.yourdomain.com/ping
2. Go to your C-panel / Cron jobs.
3. Schedule this command 'wget http://www.yourdomain/ping' every minute.

That way, your server will remain active and will be always fast on first-page load.

It works for me that way. the difference is stunning.